# i want to create dynamic sidebar in mern stack which render another component when they clicked

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

for your understanding i attached w3school screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecim3.png)

if u have ever visited w3school website u will understand my requirement easily.
i want to create these html sidebar dynamic from my admin dashboard. first i will create one sidebar title name then insert content according to title name and so on..... for best understanding you can assume that i want to create w3school clone dynamic from where i can dynamic create sidebar and content. i read about react router dom and many more but not able to create like this.

Comment: Have a look at react router https://reactrouter.com/en/main

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is simple. Attach a click event on sidebar links. Then when click event is fired on an item, you can check if the current user is a simple user or admin or any other role. And according to that you can make a redirection.

Comment: You can also render sidebar link items based on the current user role.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-router for navigation and then render according to the route
https://codesandbox.io/s/c2zs4
here is the example I found, it used react-router for navigation and render components according to the route.

Answer (score 0):

add in _app.js file

you can put a header here

```
<div className="flex">

<div className="W-2/6>
 <Sidebar/>
</div>
<div className="w-4/6">
page component here
</div>
</div>
```

and footer here

I used tailwind CSS